# slam_gmapping MappingFromLoggedData out of dual 32-bit range

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I followed the tutorial doc.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData
When I finished make index success,and began to play it, I found a error reported.
I have tried both ubuntu 32,64 bits,and it seems the same problem.

The error message is

```
 sam@sam-desktop:~/code/ros/slam/mapping$ rosbag play basic_localization_stage.bag 
 [ INFO] [1298639209.074814380]: Opening basic_localization_stage.bag
 
 Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.
 
 Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
 [FATAL] [1298639301.490772364]: Time is out of dual 32-bit      range670987.745222     
 sam@sam-desktop:~/code/ros/slam/mapping$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9280/slam_gmapping-mappingfromloggeddata-out-of-dual-32-bit-range/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-06-08**:
I use the normal ubuntu 10.10 with Diamondback installation. I didn't find any strange. what I use for installation instruction is "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-*"

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-06-07**:
I just tried that tutorial with Diamondback on a 64-bit system, and I couldn't replicate your error.  Is there anything unusual about your system?

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-06-26**:
I'm having the same issue on 64bit Ubuntu 11.10 with Fuerte.  Any luck solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
from time to time, we try and go through unanswered questions to see if answers can be provided

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-09-02**:
So Willow Garage have someone specially focus on trying to answer all the questions?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-02**:
This question is 6 months old.  At this point it is very unlikely to be answered.  People have already attempted to reproduce your problem and can't, so it's time to let the community to focus on other questions.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-09-02**:
Why you want to close this problem? This problem haven't been solved. I'm still waiting for answer.